# Vim display in statusline after delay

Tags: vim, delay, statusline

Is it possible to have the statusline in Vim be updated so and so long after a given event?

And if so, how does one do that?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? Like which problem it is that you are trying to solve?

Comment: in my vimrc there is a shortcut which implements a functionality. i want to have the script report back that the functionality has been successfully implemented. but i dont want the report of the functionality having been successful, to stay on the statusline indefinitely.

Comment: @Hermann: Then when do you wish the statusline to revert to its default settings? I.e, which event? When you write a buffer, for instance?

Comment: i want it to revert to its default settings after say, 3 seconds. So its not really an event.

Comment: Bad luck. `:timer` is yet to be implemented (but is on the [todo list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/todo.html#todo.txt)). Would you like to pick an event?

Comment: what do you mean, pick an event?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to report the success of your operation in the status line, rather than, say, using an `:echo` command?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, using timed changes to the statusline is not possible at the moment. However, if you can pick a suitable event at which the status reverts to the default, then you might be in luck. For e.g., if your workflow is:

1. `Esc` out to normal mode and call your shortcut
2. See the outcome on the statusline and go back to insert mode to continue working

then you could use the `InsertEnter` event in an autocommand to change the status to the default once you hit <kbd>i</kbd> in normal mode.

Here's a small fun example that you can probably modify to your needs.

#### The normal status line:

[image]

```
"statusline
hi green term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=107
hi red term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=167
hi gray term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=0
hi lblue term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=12

function! Palpatine()
    let str='At last, the Jedi are no more' 
    return str
endfunction

function! Force()
    let str=',~`,~`,~`,~`,~`,~`,~`,~'
    return str
endfunction

function! DefaultStatus()
    let statusStr='%#red#Palpatine: %#gray#%{Palpatine()} %#lblue#%{Force()} %=%#green#Yoda'
    return statusStr
endfunction

set laststatus=2
set statusline=%!DefaultStatus()
```

#### Statuschange on function call:

[image]

```
function! Yoda()
    let str='Not if anything to say about it, I have'
    return str
endfunction

function! MyStatus()
    let statusStr='%#red#Palpatine %=%#lblue#%{Force()} %#gray#%{Yoda()} %#green#:Yoda'
    return statusStr
endfunction

function! MyFunc()
    set statusline=%!MyStatus()
endfunction

noremap <C-m> :call MyFunc()<CR>
```

With the above definitions, every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>, the statusline  changes to the above.

Now by setting an autocommand, we can revert it to the default whenever you enter insert mode.

```
autocmd InsertEnter * set statusline=%!DefaultStatus()
```

#### Back to insert:

[image]

Comment: you get a +1 just for re-enacting Star Wars in your vim statusline! But then of all the lines in the series, you picked _Revenge of the Sith_????